Do my employer's contributions count towards the Roth limit of $7k Roth contributions?
I just got a new job and I'm trying to decide how much to contribute to my retirement.  I know Roth has a $7000/yr limit. Does that amount include any employer contributions? My job matches up to 4%; I would be putting in 4% (to bring me to that $7000) but if they matched me it would put exceed that $7000 limit, by double. So, I need to know if their match counts.

A Roth IRA is an individual plan, separate from what your employer offers. You may be confusing it with a Roth 401(k) at work, where your employer can match contributions--albeit into a pre-tax 401(k). 401(k)s have a higher limit: $23,000 for younger employees in 2024.
Your employer's contributions have no effect on what you can contribute to your Roth IRA.

they have no effect on 401k limits, either

So if I want their match contributions I would need to also contribute to their 403B (their non profit so no 401k), then the Roth is my contributions alone?

To clarify -- nothing you or your employer contributed to a work 401(k) or 403(b) (Roth or otherwise) will impact your ability to contribute to a personal Roth IRA.
At work you may have the option to contribute to a a 403(b) in either Roth or traditional forms.  This is a completely separate pool of money than personal IRAs with separate limits.  Prior to 2024, if you contributed to a Roth 403(b), then employer contributions/matching would be to a pre-tax 403(b) account.  In theory in 2024 employers may match to a Roth 403(b), but that is uncommon.

@JeremyRichards That's interesting about Roth matching not having to go into a pre-tax account anymore, was not aware of that change. I can't imagine a lot of employers making that change though because it means they have to pay tax on that amount, but employees probably won't appreciate the difference.

@NicoleMiller Correct, if you want employer matching contributions you would have to contribute to the pre-tax 403(b) or Roth 403(b).

IIRC, the only relationship between 401k and IRA is that being covered by a 401k at work may limit your ability to make tax-deductible contributions to a regular IRA (Roth IRA contributions are never deductible). Non-deductible contributions are not affected.

@CraigW actually employees would be the ones paying the tax, not the employers.

@littleadv So it's like the employer contributes the matching amount pre-tax, followed by an immediate in-plan conversion to Roth?

@CraigW if that makes it easier to understand. It's just going to show up on paystubs as salary paid and after-tax deduction.

@Barmar Roth IRA contributions are also not permitted at all for high-income earners who are covered by a 401(k)/403(b) plan from their work. As I remember it, one didn't need to participate in the plan in order to forfeit the eligibility to make Roth IRA contributions; that the plan was offered to the employees was enough to trigger the ban.

@CraigW:  My understanding is that employer Roth matching will be handled as showing still as a pre-tax deduction, but at the end of the year you will receive a 1099 showing those funds as income to you.  It is your responsibility to reconcile that at tax time.
